# How to change the resolution of DS18B20?

Tags: temperature-sensor

I'm using [DS18B20](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) sensor with [this library](https://github.com/milesburton/Arduino-Temperature-Control-Library), the 750ms delay is causing problem in timer part of my code. the code below is from DallasTemperature.cpp:

```
// returns number of milliseconds to wait till conversion is complete (based on IC datasheet)
int16_t DallasTemperature::millisToWaitForConversion(uint8_t bitResolution) {

    switch (bitResolution) {
    case 9:
        return 94;
    case 10:
        return 188;
    case 11:
        return 375;
    default:
        return 750;
    }
```

I'm reading the temperature like this:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>
#define ONE_WIRE_BUS A0
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

void setup() {}

void loop () {
    float currentTemp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);
    sensors.requestTemperatures();
}
```

*sensor is not connected in parasite mode, and there is only one sensor.*

How can i change the resolution from 12 to 9 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple:

```
sensors.setResolution(9);
```

It normally defaults to 9, but then probes the connected device to find the maximum resolution it supports and sets it to that. This would normally be done in `sensors.begin()` which you omitted from your snippet above. If you don't have that it will be on 9 bit anyway, and also the bus probably won't work regardless.

Comment: thanks, do i have to declare the address too? sensors.begin(); sensors.setResolution(9); should be in void setup?

Comment: `sensors.begin()` finds the number of sensors connected and works out the maximum resolution supported. `sensors.setResolution(9)` sets the resolution for all future transactions for all connected devices.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work better:

```
sensors.setResolution(tempDeviceAddress, TEMPERATURE_PRECISION);
```